# How to set event to the device calendar through my app?

Tags: java, android, events, calendar

I have date fields in my application.On clicking a button I want to set these dates in the android device calendar and it must remind on the same date regarding the event.
How can I implement this?
please somebody help me with similar kind of example.

Thanks in advance.

Please somebody help me how to set the date which is in edittext to device calendar in android? I am new to android and I am trying this from last one day,I did not get any idea about this. Please can anybody explain me with the example???

Answer (score 0):

First,you must dynamically generate a calendar.
you can set an event to the calendar,on clicking the date. With `JSONArray and JSONObject` from Fragment Manager, you can  interact with content provider and also with server.After retrieving necessary details you can fix the alert on mentioned date weekly,monthly and yearly.